# Make Mousetrap work with Greasemonkey select text fields?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, event-listener

Wondering how to get Greasemonkey to work with Mousetrap (http://craig.is/killing/mice) where it will trigger a function when text is selected. It mentions in the API something about it, but I don't know how to get it to work for an entire page and not just one field.

> Text fields
>
> By default all keyboard events will not fire if you are inside of a textarea, input, or select to prevent undesirable things from happening.
>
> If for whatever reason you want them to you can add the class mousetrap to the element.

```
<textarea name="message" class="mousetrap"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no option in Mousetrap to do this.

You could, however, achieve this through some simple JQuery.  Something like this should do the trick:

`$(':input').addClass('mousetrap');`

I am considering making the `_stop()` method public in Mousetrap which would allow people to extend it to work a way other than the default.